# Mutation of a mutable data-member via pointer-to-member

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, mutable

The Standard provide the following note:

> [ Note: it is not possible to use a pointer to member that refers to a
>   mutable member to modify a const class object. For example,
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     S() : i(0) { }
>     mutable int i;
> };
> void f()
> {
>     const S cs;
>     int S::* pm = &S::i; // pm refers to mutable member S::i
>     cs.*pm = 88; // ill-formed: cs is a const object
> }
> ```
>
> -end note]

But we can use just object-expression to modify const object which has a mutale data member.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    A(){ }
    mutable int a;
};
const A a;

int main()
{
    a.a = 4;
    std::cout << a.a; //4
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0cbab21f9042e64)**

But ISO/IEC Derictive tells

> Notes and examples integrated in the text of a document shall only be
>   used for giving additional information intended to assist the
>   understanding or use of the document. They shall not contain
>   requirements ("shall"; see 3.3.1 and Table H.1) or any information
>   considered indispensable for the use of the document [...]

Which means the note I provide at the beginning of my Q is not a requirement.

I'm looking for a normative requirement explcitly precludes such using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before that note you will find the following:

> The restrictions on cv-qualiﬁcation, and the manner in which the cv-qualiﬁers of the operands are combined to produce the cv-qualiﬁers of the result, are the same as the rules for E1.E2 given in 5.2.5

Jump up to 5.2.5 and you'll find this:

> If E2 is a non-static data member and the type of E1 is “cq1 vq1 X”, and the type of E2 is “cq2 vq2 T”, the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the ﬁrst expression. If E1 is an lvalue, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; otherwise E1.E2 is an xvalue. Let the notation vq12 stand for the “union” of vq1 and vq2; that is, if vq1 or vq2 is volatile, then vq12 is volatile. Similarly, let the notation cq12 stand for the “union” of cq1 and cq2; that is, **if cq1 or cq2 is const, then cq12 is const.** If E2 is declared to be a mutable member, then the type of E1.E2 is “vq12 T”. If E2 is not declared to be a mutable member, then the type of E1.E2 is “cq12 vq12 T”.

The union of the const qualifiers in `cs.*pm` is `const`, the exception for `mutable` members doesn't apply to pointers.

It's easier to understand if you consider that storage class specifiers are not part of the type, so how would the compiler be able to distinguish between `mutable` and non-`mutable` pointers to member?

```
struct S;

void f(const S& s, int S::* pm)
{
  s.*pm = 1; // How do I know if pm points to a mutable member? S isn't even defined!
}
```

Simply put, there is no such thing as a pointer to a `mutable` member, just as there is no such thing as a pointer to a `static` member, the pointed type's storage class is unknown (the type can only be qualified by `const` and / or `volatile`).

Comment: Not clear. You're right the union of the const qualifiers in cs.*pm is const. But _If E2 is declared to be a mutable member, then the type of E1.E2 is “vq12 T”_. Which means cs.*pm isn't const-qualified.

Comment: E2 in this case is not a mutable member, it's a *pointer* to member, which may or may not be `mutable`, that information has already been lost.

Comment: The Standard at the end of 5.5/2: _The result is an object or a function of the type specified by the second operand_ that's in our case it's just `int`. Is it what you mean?

Comment: The type is unimportant, what's important is that `mutable` is never going to be part of the information held by a pointer because it's a storage class specifier, but I'm having a hard time trying to find a good ambiguous example.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Updated the example, it's contrived but it should help explain the concept.

Comment: _How do I know if pm points to a mutable member?_ You don't, but why the quote from 5.5/2 I cite in the comment above isn't suit here? It _does_ say that the result is an object specified by the second operand which means an object the mutable specifier we don't know about.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Again, storage classes are **not** part of the type of an object, the result of the `.*` operator can **never** be assumed to be a `mutable` object, even if the pointer itself points to a `mutable` member.